# Primefaces ExceptionHandler not working as in the showcase

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, exception

I've tried the new ExceptionHandler tag in primefaces but it seems that I'm missing something with this tag.

Basically my code is the same as in http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/exceptionHandler.xhtml , the problem is that adding this tag doesn't change anything I'm not getting any thing on client side.
The standard js API is not working either with prime buttons:

```
jsf.ajax.addOnError(function(data) {alert('Error');})
```

The only difference I've noticed between my running app and Primefaces showcase is that the ajax response I get is different from the showcase's one:

My response:

[image]

showcases's response

[image]

here is  the code

```
<h:form>
<h3 style="margin-top:0">AJAX</h3>
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{exceptionHandlerView.throwViewExpiredException}"
                 ajax="true"
                 value="Throw ViewExpiredException!" />
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{exceptionHandlerView.throwNullPointerException}"
                 ajax="true"
                 value="Throw NullPointerException!" />
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{exceptionHandlerView.throwWrappedIllegalStateException}"
                 ajax="true"
                 value="Throw IllegalStateException!" />

<h3>Non-AJAX</h3>
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{exceptionHandlerView.throwViewExpiredException}"
                 ajax="false"
                 value="Throw ViewExpiredException!" />
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{exceptionHandlerView.throwNullPointerException}"
                 ajax="false"
                 value="Throw NullPointerException!" />


<p:ajaxExceptionHandler type="javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException"
                        update="exceptionDialog"
                        onexception="PF('exceptionDialog').show();" />

<p:ajaxExceptionHandler type="java.lang.NullPointerException"
                        update="exceptionDialog"
                        onexception="PF('exceptionDialog').show();" />

<p:dialog id="exceptionDialog" header="Exception '#{pfExceptionHandler.type}' occured!" widgetVar="exceptionDialog"
          height="500px">
    Message: #{pfExceptionHandler.message} <br/>
    StackTrace: <h:outputText value="#{pfExceptionHandler.formattedStackTrace}" escape="false" /> <br />

    <p:button onclick="document.location.href = document.location.href;"
              value="Reload!"
              rendered="#{pfExceptionHandler.type == 'javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException'}" />
</p:dialog>
```

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.view.misc;


import javax.faces.FacesException;
import javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ExceptionHandlerView {

    public void throwNullPointerException() {
        throw new NullPointerException("A NullPointerException!");
    }

    public void throwWrappedIllegalStateException() {
        Throwable t = new IllegalStateException("A wrapped IllegalStateException!");
        throw new FacesException(t);
    }

    public void throwViewExpiredException() {
        throw new ViewExpiredException("A ViewExpiredException!",
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open the by you given showcase link once again. Now click the *Documentation* tab. You'll see among others:

> ## 11.3 Exception Handler
>
> PrimeFaces provides a built-in exception handler to take care of exceptions in ajax and non-ajax
>   requests easily.
>
> ### Configuration
>
> ExceptionHandler and an ElResolver configured is required in faces configuration file.
>
> ```
> <application>
>      <el-resolver>
>          org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver
>     </el-resolver>
> </application>
> <factory>
>     <exception-handler-factory>
>        org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory
>     </exception-handler-factory>
> </factory>
> ```

Act accordingly.